# What is "vi" as related to IDEs?

Tags: vi

I've heard the term used, but can't seem to find any solid references that describe what it is, what it's used for, or anything of the sort. Sorry if this question is off-topic, not sure at all where to go.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try reading [the Wiki explaination](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vi) of vi.. It is an incredibly powerful but not very user friendly until you get to know it editor, you can get it for windows if you really want.

Answer (score 2):

`vi` is a text editor used in Linux system.

Answer (score 1):

Vi is  text editor.

Learning it well can increase your productivity in ways that might amaze you.

The basic idea of vi is that it allows you to move around a file and operate on text by *typing* commands.